# When can 2 different simplicial chains share the same boundary?

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex, topological-data-analysis

Suppose I have a filtration of a simplicial complex $K$:
$$
\emptyset=K_0\subseteq K_1\subseteq K_2\subseteq,...,\subseteq K_n=K
$$

Suppose $\sigma_j$ is a $d$-dimensional simplex that first appears in $K_j$ and $\gamma_i$ is a $d-1$-dimensional simplex that appears first in $K_i$ where $i<j$. Additionally, there is a chain in $c\in C_d(K_j)$ (i.e the free group generated by the $d$-dimensional simplexes in $K_j$) such that $c=a_j\sigma_j+\sum a_k\sigma_k$ and $a_j\not=0$ such that the boundary of $c$ has $\gamma_i$ as a non-zero summand. Is it possible to show that the boundary of $c$ is not the boundary of any other $d$-dimensional chain in $C_d(k_h)$ where $i\leq h<j$?

The reason I ask is because in persistent homology, we use a form of gaussian elimination to calculate the birth and death barcodes of a persistent module: https://geometry.stanford.edu/papers/zc-cph-05/zc-cph-05.pdf (Pg:8-9). So in the above situation, the homology class of boundary of $c$ is said to be born in $K_i$ but dies in $K_j$. However, I don't see why it can't be the case that there exists a chain $l$ in $K_h$, where $i\leq h<j$ such that $l$ also has the same boundary as $c$.

Can someone explain what is going on?

Comment: What if $c$ is the upper hemisphere of (a triangulation of) $S^d$ and $\gamma_i$ a simplex on the equator $S^{d-1}$? Then the boundary of $c$ is also the boundary of the lower hemisphere.

Comment: Yeah I had a similar counter example. But i don't understand how the paper concluded otherwise. I think it has something to do with the birth timings.

Comment: I think we need more information from the setup in that paper. I took a brief look but couldn't match your question with any parts of the paper.

Comment: It is corollary 4.1. After the they get the column echelon form, they look at the pivot columns. "If row i has pivot $\tilde{M}_k(i,j)=t^n$ it contributes degree $$\Sigma^{\operatorname{deg} \tilde{e}_{i}} F[t] / t^{n}$$ to the description..". So $e_j$ has a boundary corresponding to the sum of the nonzero row elements in its column. However, that boundary apparently is not the boundary of any other chain at a lower filtration level until it reaches the filtration of $e_j$ where it dies off. That is what i don't get. How does the boundary survive until it reaches the filtration level of $e_j$.